# OpenCV 3.0.0 C++: Cannot get knn->load("file.yml") to work

Tags: c++, opencv, knn

I have saved the knn model successfully using knn->save("file.yml").. But cannot seem to load the model using knn->load("file.yml")... Is something wring with the formatting of the load command??

Help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Ptr<KNearest> svm = Algorithm::load<KNearest>("treino.knn");
```

or

```
Ptr<KNearest> svm = KNearest::load<KNearest>("treino.knn");
```